# JMeter: Shows "Object Moved Here", though value is extracted using Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter, token, extractor

I am capturing token value using Regular Expression Extractor, still I can see "Object moved to here." in response data.

Below are the details:

**Regular Expression**:

```
name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="([A-Za-z0-9+=/\-\_]+?)"
```

**Template**: `$1$`

Token value in view result is:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="lRqCm7bYMLnpwBFgQk001juxKm5L9FN3ydzyMCzKcoAnnbQsaLU_0TPRt3Tccg-T0CSFzFuXa3DqSvZGzC1dLoWdoumaZFQ5daLaqiu3MFY1" />
```

Please let me know how can I extract value.

Comment: Use `value="([^"<]+)"`, it will help you get the value attribute value with any characters in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier solution is to use [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor).

You would configure it this way:

[image]